# Unsupported Processor BSOD in Safe Mode

Tags: windows-10, bsod, intel-core-i7, safe-mode, windows-10-v1909

1. My computer works perfectly in Normal Mode.
2. When I try to boot into Safe Mode, I am greeted with BSOD and the stop code "UNSUPPORTED_PROCESSOR". The computer then reboots itself into Normal Mode again.

The processor is an Intel i7-8700K. How do I start debugging this? I would like to boot into Safe Mode to delete some drivers that are always in use in Normal Mode.

Comment: You start by advising the model of processor. This strikes me as being a driver related issue. Why would you want to remove in-use drivers? If you really want to risk stuffing up your - apparently already fragile - sustem, you could try doing thus operation in Linux.

Comment: Updated to add the processor model. Although I added the specific reason that I currently want to boot into Safe Mode, I'm sure other reasons will arise in the future. So I'm really looking for help resolving the inability to boot into Safe Mode.

Comment: That is a curious bugcheck code - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x5d--unsupported-processor does a minidump file get created even?  I.e. under \windows\minidump\. If so can you link it?

Comment: Right? There's no way Windows 10 doesn't support an 8th gen i7. No crashdumps or minidumps unfortunately :(

Comment: I would back up your data and do a clean reinstall of 1909, see if still does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating my BIOS fixed this for me. In my case Safe Boot was not working with [ASRock Z370 Killer SLI/ac BIOS](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/Z370%20Killer%20SLIac/index.asp#BIOS) version 3.30, but it does work with version 4.30. I know that Windows uses a newer version of microcode for the i7-8700K than the BIOS version 3.30 that I was using. Perhaps Normal Mode is able to handle an older microcode from the BIOS where Safe Mode is not ‍♂️